# Android display foreign language strings

Tags: java, android, json, string

I have an app where I retrieve some data in JSON format. Some of the strings in the JSON file are in foreign languages such as Arabic, Hindi, etc. I've tried decoding the string using `UTF-8` but it stills shows gibberish, not the original script. Any idea how I can achieve this?

EDIT: My method of decoding the string from JSON

```
String result; // result in string format obtained from server

JSONTokener tokener = new JSONTokener(result);

JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(tokener);

String msg = obj.getString("message");

TextView message = TextView) findViewById(R.id.inbox_msg);

try {

message.setText(new String(msg.getBytes(), "UTF-8"));

} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Anything wrong I'm doing?

P.S. : I tried using a DroidHindi.ttf file to display the text, but it didn't work. I'm running the app on a Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 7.0

Comment: Can you verify if it decodes the correct unicode points? If so, I'd second MDMalik and blame the font you are using.

Comment: @Fildor didn't you "If so, I'd second ......"

Comment: Frankly, this is the first time I've handled decoding. So could you tell me how to check if it is decoding the right unicode points?

Comment: @MDMalik Yes? OK, it could still be both: Bad unicode *and* bad font.

Comment: Well I'm using the default fonts on the device. I'm not sure if that would cause the problem.

Comment: @Rameez: Just take a font of which you *know* it can display arab or hindi or whatever you desire. If there still is rubbish displayed: check the encoding.

Comment: Can you display the desired characters with that default font?

Comment: Nope. So all I have to do is pick a font which can display any conceivable language in the world? :P

Comment: Well it is enough if the font can display all unicode points you are expecting. Whenever I encountered something like this it was one of the two: the font didn't have a graphic for the code or the encoding was messed with (ASCII instead of unicode or sth. like that). [This](http://www.unicode.org/charts/index.html) is a good starting point for all unicode-related issues.

Comment: I've posted some code above. Please check that out.

Answer (score 1):

Android supports arabic language in default.for hindi in server side you should unicode the hindi text  and in client side(android) decode the text and print the value. remember that in both client side and server side u should use same font to unicode and decode the text.(In ex i have used Kruti DEv 10.TTF). http://www.infowebservices.in/hindi/   refer this site to convert hindi text to unicode else use some library.

```
LinearLayout mainLayout=new LinearLayout(this);
        mainLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        setContentView(mainLayout);

        TextView arbicView=new TextView(this);
        arbicView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); 
        arbicView.setText("الغارديان: انقسام بين سكان الجولان حول نظام الاسد");
        mainLayout.addView(arbicView);


        TextView hindiView=new TextView(this);
        hindiView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); 
        hindiView.setText("Hghgfdhgfhsdgfh h hhfh hkshfkuifyeryeuiryhdfjkhdfuiyerihjkfhsdjkyruiweyk");
        hindiView.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Kruti Dev 10.TTF"));
        mainLayout.addView(hindiView);
```